# How to format a LaTeX string in python?

Tags: python, string, latex, format

I'm writing an application, part of whose functionality is to generate LaTeX CVs, so I find myself in a situation where I have strings like

```
\begin{document}
\title{Papers by AUTHOR}
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle
\begin{enumerate}

%%   LIST OF PAPERS
%%   Please comment out anything between here and the
%%   first \item
%%   Please send any updates or corrections to the list to
%%   XXXEMAIL???XXX

%\usepackage[pdftex, ...
```

which I would like to populate with dynamic information, e.g. an email address.  Due to the format of LaTeX itself, .format with the {email} syntax won't work, and neither will using a dictionary with the %(email)s syntax.  Edit: in particular, strings like "\begin{document}" (a command in LaTeX) should be left literally as they are, without replacement from .format, and strings like "%%" (a comment in LaTeX) should also be left, without replacement from a populating dictionary. What's a reasonable way to do this?

Comment: Operating here under the assumption that I don't really want to have to type %% for % everywhere...

Comment: What version of Python are you using? str.format() is new to 2.6

Comment: Have you ever finished this library, because I just created something like it: https://github.com/JelteF/PyLaTeX

Comment: Cool!  I did finish working on this project, the source for which you can find at http://invenio-software.org/ (still developed by others, not by me).  I didn't split out the LaTeX piece into anything nice, so it's a good thing someone did.  :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why won't this work?

```
>>> output = r'\author{{email}}'.format(email='user@example.org')
>>> print output
\author{email}
```

*edit*: Use double curly braces to "escape" literal curly braces that only LaTeX understands:

```
>>> output = r'\begin{{document}} ... \author{{{email}}}'.format(
... email='user@example.org')
>>> print output
\begin{document} ... \author{user@example.org}
```

Comment: out = r'''
   ...: \begin{document}
   ...: {{email}}'''.format(email='user@example.com')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/valkyrie/projects/invenio/modules/websearch/lib/<ipython console> in <module>()

KeyError: 'document'

Comment: the LaTeX contains things with curly braces that should be kept unmodified (including the curly braces themselves).

Comment: So use double-curly braces for those (essentially escaping them.

Comment: It's sort of a shame that the only outs are doubling on curlies or percents, but as long as it works, I guess it's all good.  :)

Answer (score 5):

You may not use the new `format` syntax to avoid escaping the `{` and `}`.

That should work:

```
>>> a = r'''
\title{%(title)s}
\author{%(author)s}
\begin{document}'''

>>> b = a % {'title': 'My Title', 'author': 'Me, Of course'}
>>> print(b)

\title{My Title}
\author{Me, Of course}
\begin{document}
```

You should use raw strings `r'something'` to avoid escaping `\` as `\\`.

PS: You should take a look on [txt2tags](http://txt2tags.org/), a Python script to convert t2t formatted text into html, latex, markdown etc. Check the source code to see how these conversions are done.

Comment: It complains about LaTeX's comments, e.g. I have a line which says "%\usepackage...." that causes the dictionary formatter to complain.  I will look into txt2tags, though, thank you!

Comment: You can add comments after formatting... Or escape the `%` with `\%`.