# Format a LaTeX math string in Python 3

Tags: string, python-3.x, math, latex

I see it is possible to use the format method on a LaTeX string in python by using a double curly bracket as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672213/how-to-format-a-latex-string-in-python#6672249). For instance:

```
In[1]: 'f_{{{0}}}'.format('in')
Out[1]: 'f_{in}'
```

But how can I use the format method in a math LaTeX string? (particularly for subscripts)

For example, with:

```
In[2]: r'$f_{in,{{0}}}$'.format('a')
```

I would expect:

```
Out[2]: '$f_{in,a}$'
```

But I get a

```
ValueError: unexpected '{' in field name
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct statement for `In[2]` should be:

```py
r'$f_{{in,{0}}}$'.format('a')
# gives '$f_{in,a}$'
```

Here's an illustration for clarity:

```
'$f_{{ in, {0} }}$'.format('in')
    ^^_________^^
    these curly braces are escaped, which leaves 'in, {0}' at the center
```

**Explanation:** 
The problem with `r'$f_{in,{{0}}}$'.format('a')` was that the curly brace `{` following `$f_`, and the curly brace `}` preceding `$` needed to be escaped as well, which is what caused the `ValueError`.

---

**To understand this further**, the same set of curly braces (that `f_` encloses) of the statement in `In[1]`, `'f_{{{0}}}'.format('in')`, was also escaped. When you reduce this, you'll notice that `{0}` is left within these set of curly braces which allows for `'in'` to be substituted in. Therefore, we evaluated to simply a `f_{in}` in `Out[1]`. Here's an illustration for clarity:

```
'f_{{ {0} }}'.format('in')
   ^^_____^^
     these curly braces are escaped, which leaves {0} at the center

# gives 'f_{in}'
```

Comment: Thanks! Very useful explanation.