# matplotlib text and displaying value from a variable

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I add or display a value from a variable in text added to the plot in matplotlib? I place the text in the upper left corner but I need to display an average value stored in a variable. I'm not sure where and how to add the variable `avg_bedt`. `avg_bedt` is calculated in advance. Adding text works fine. Here follows the code:

```
ax.text(2.5, 9.5, r'Average bedtime: $\bar{t}_{ab} = $', size=10, ha='center', va='center')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format a LaTeX math string in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48313125/format-a-latex-math-string-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, where `A1` is your average value:

```
avg_bedt=str(2.53)

ax.text(2.5, 9.5, r'Average bedtime:'+avg_bedt, size=10, ha='center', va='center')
```