# .format in Python Latex String Error nested curly brakets

Tags: python, string, format, latex

I get a very similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48313125/format-a-latex-math-string-in-python-3) except it does not solve my problem or I dont understand the solution?

```
r"($\sqrt{{0}}$)".format(unit)
```

gives me `'($\\sqrt{0}$)'`
and `r"($\sqrt{ {0} }$)".format(unit)`, `r"($\sqrt{in, {0} }$)".format(unit)` throws me this error:

```
ValueError: unexpected '{' in field name
```

How to insert the unit into the latex string?